# Comparing integers in columns with nulls?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table. The table has two integer columns. Nulls are allowed in each column. The following query works

```
 select * from table where col1=1 and col2 = 2
```

but neither of the following two queries work

```
 select * from table where col1=1 and col2 != 2 or
 select * from table where col1=1 and col2 <> = 2
```

I am aware that the comparison operators are not supposed to work for columns that have null, but '=' is a comparison operator and the first query above works. I do not understand why the first query works and the second query does not? (If you see any typos just ignore them I tested this with real code any mistakes are just when I transcribed it to this question.)

Here are two sql statements that will allow you to create a table and insert data into it for testing the above queries.

```
  CREATE TABLE Test (
  ID int,
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int)
```

and the insert statements

```
 INSERT INTO test 
    (id, col1 , col2)
 VALUES 
    (1,1,NULL),
    (2,NULL,2),
    (3,1,2)
```

Comment: These queries will work regardless of null or not. It's just that an comparison operator involving null will return unknown instead of true or false, so the results might not be as you expect. Add exactly what you mean by the queries don't work. It may help if you add sample data and expected results.

Comment: The  first query returns the correct number of rows. The second queries (either one) returns zero rows but I know that there are many rows that actually satisfy the query. In the table, col2 either has a 2 in it or a null. col1 either has a 1 in it or a null.

Comment: Add the `CREATE TABLE` with `INSERT` statements so that we can better help you.

Comment: Ok, I have added the sql that will create a table and then insert 3 rows into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help you understand by examining the results of each query predicate individually using the sample data. Note that both conditions must evaluate to TRUE for a row to be returned due to the AND logical operator.

```
select * from Test where col1=1 and col2 = 2;

 VALUES 
    (1,1,NULL), --col1=1 is TRUE and col2 = 2 is UNKNOWN
    (2,NULL,2), --col1=1 is UNKNOWN and col2 = 2 is TRUE
    (3,1,2)     --col1=1 is TRUE and col2 = 2 is TRUE: row returned because both are TRUE

select * from table where col1=1 and col2 <> 2
 VALUES 
    (1,1,NULL), --col1=1 is TRUE and col2 <> 2 is UNKNOWN
    (2,NULL,2), --col1=1 is UNKNOWN and col2 <> 2 is FALSE
    (3,1,2)     --col1=1 is TRUE and col2 <> 2 is FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If Col 2 is either 2 or null as in your comment then you need to use IS NULL

```
select * from table where col1=1 and col2 IS NULL
```

Or convert the null values to some other non-used value

```
select * from table where col1=1 and ISNULL(col2, 0) != 2
```

Sounds like those columns should really be bit fields though to me.

Comment: Yes col2 is either 2 or null. But col1 is either 1 or null also. So why do I have to use ISNULL for the second query but I do not have to use it for the first query?